# What is a primitive element in a Fuchsian group?

Tags: complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry, fundamental-groups

I am reading some introductory texts about Selberg's trace formula for hyperbolic surfaces and I have encountered the concept of "primitive element" $\gamma$ in a hyperbolic Fuchsian group $\Gamma \subset PSL_2(\Bbb R)$. I don't understand its definition, in fact I understand it in two ways:

- $\gamma$ is primitive if and only if it generates its own centralizer (i.e. commutant subgroup) $C(\gamma) \subset \Gamma$ (formally, $C(\gamma) = \langle \gamma \rangle$);
- $\gamma$ is primitive if and only if the equality $\gamma = \mu ^n$ with $n >0$ implies $\gamma = \mu$ (i.e. $\gamma$ has "no radicals" in $\Gamma$).

My questions are:

- is any of the two understandings above the correct one?
- if both are correct, how to prove that they are equivalent?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There are different definitions of "primitive elements" for Fuchsian groups $\Gamma$, e.g., see the definition [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=GtyFAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA38&lpg=PA38&dq=primitive+element+in+a+fuchsian+group&source=bl&ots=mCIUkiLpcs&sig=qz0Rdd2rtuPoR7bN0YFiTZzRw3Q&hl=de&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjelp-mr83NAhVDuhoKHTtSCPIQ6AEIOzAE). What is common to all definitions ( I hope), is that
an element $\gamma_0\in \Gamma$ is primitive, iff $\gamma_0=\gamma^n$ for some $\gamma \in \Gamma$ implies $n=\pm 1$.

Comment: I don't know what to say: my Fuchsian group contains only hyperbolic elements that act properly discontinuous; in particular, its elements *cannot* have fixed points in the *upper half-space*, so the stability group is trivial. Maybe your groups act on some other space ($\Bbb C \cup \{\infty\}$, maybe)?

Comment: There are several different definitions of "primitive elements" for groups $\Gamma$,  saying more or less that $\gamma$ is primitive if it is not a non-trivial power of another element. Which source do you use for your definition ?

Comment: Jens Marklof's [introductory notes](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0407288) are a good starting point. The source, though, is not important: it seems that we are using the term "Fuchsian group" in different contexts.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I would probably prefer then your second definition, and look up the proof in Marklof's notes (see Lemma $6$ ff.), that the first one is equivalent (which I find less enlightning).

Comment: By taking a look at your reference, I've notice that in proposition 2.2 the Fuchsian group acts on $\hat {\Bbb C}$, as suspected, which is not of much help in my case (I'm working on $\Bbb H$).

Comment: Yes, but it also acts on $\mathbb{H}$, as is mentioned one line earlier. So this is not a problem. The second definition you have is working for both, and the equivalence, which you wanted, is also clear.